# Python annotations for decorated async functions

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, python-decorators, aiohttp, python-typing

I have difficulties with annotations for my coroutines which are decorated to prevent aiohttp errors.
There are my two functions:

```
from typing import Callable, Awaitable, Optional
from os import sep
import aiofiles
import aiohttp
from asyncio.exceptions import TimeoutError
from aiohttp.client_exceptions import ClientError


def catch_aiohttp_errors(func: Callable[..., Awaitable]) -> Callable[..., Awaitable]:
    async def wrapper(*args):
        try:
            return await func(*args)
        except (TimeoutError, ClientError):
            return None
    return wrapper


@catch_aiohttp_errors
async def download(url: str, download_path: str, filename: str, suffix: str) -> Optional[str]:
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            async with aiofiles.open(download_path + sep + filename + '.' + suffix, 'wb') as file:
                async for chunk in response.content.iter_chunked(1024):
                    await file.write(chunk) if chunk else await file.write(b'')
    return download_path + sep + filename + '.' + suffix
```

The main reason to make decorator function is that i have several async functions using aiohttp, and i don't want to write `try/except` statements in every similar function.

The problem i faced is correct annotation for my second function.
As you can see, it returns `str`. But if there will be errors, it will return `None` according to `try/except` part of the decorator function.
Is it correct to annotate such function with `Optional[str]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using `TypeVar` as `Awaitable` type parameter to stop losing information about decorated function: in your example result of call to `download` would be of type `Any`. Also using `ParamSpec` will help preserve arguments. Finally, something like this should work (assuming python 3.10, replace all unknown `typing` imports with `typing_extensions` otherwise):

```py
from typing import Callable, Awaitable, Optional, TypeVar, ParamSpec
from functools import wraps


_T = TypeVar('_T')
_P = ParamSpec('_P')

def catch_aiohttp_errors(func: Callable[_P, Awaitable[_T]]) -> Callable[_P, Awaitable[Optional[_T]]]:
    
    @wraps(func)
    async def wrapper(*args: _P.args, **kwargs: _P.kwargs) -> Optional[_T]:
        try:
            return await func(*args)
        except Exception:
            return None
    
    return wrapper
    

@catch_aiohttp_errors
async def download(url: str, download_path: str, filename: str, suffix: str) -> str:
    return 'foo'
```

Now `download` has signature

```
def (url: builtins.str, download_path: builtins.str, filename: builtins.str, suffix: builtins.str) -> typing.Awaitable[Union[builtins.str, None]]
```

Also you don't have to add `Optional` manually now - decorator will do. [Playground with this solution](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=85d91d30f499edb260c585807add321b)